# How can I deploy an app in GAE without lowering my security settings?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine

I have been trying to deploy an app with Google's appengine (with Python), but I get an "access denied" error, and an email from google saying someone tried to enter my account (me, of course). In the same email it says that I can lower my security settings to resolve the issue, and while it does work, it says it is not recommended.

I read somewhere else that it could be related to the system's clock, but I think mine is working just fine. Any ideas of how to solve it without lowering the security settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either:

- Append the `--oauth2` parameter at the end of your `appcfg.py` deploying command which will open a page in your browser where you will need to authenticate into your Google account and then a token will be permanently stored in a file on your filesystem which will be reused the next time you deploy without requiring you to re-authenticate ([see more](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2)).

or

- Enable [two-factor authentication](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) and generate an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) which you will use only for GAE deployments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one other thing. If I'm using the GUI instead of the command line, how can I stay logged in or remember the password (there is no "Remember me" checkbox)?

Comment: I don't use the GUI Launcher often but I do see a "Remember Password in Keychain" option on my osx machine. If you are using a different OS/are not seeing it and If you'd rather not work in terminal then you could simply create a batch/shell file with something like `appcfg.py --oauth2  update <PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT>` and launch it every time you need to deploy your code. This will ask you to authenticate one time only and will remember the token so that you won't have to do that again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.